# Visual Studio Code Меню с названием Функций

Tags: веб-программирование, ide, visual-studio-code

Есть ли плагин для Visual Studio Code который выводил бы список функций в конкретном файле ?

Что-то наподобие navigator в netbeans / outline в eclipse / navbar atom

Comment: В теории по Ctrl+Shift+O можно переключаться между функциями, но похоже что это работает не для всех языков. Я использую vscode для lua и у меня не работает.

Comment: Рекомендую добавить метку "visual-studio-code" и поменять заголовок.